# df and du show different size and The size of the "/platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr.so.1

Tags: solaris, disk-space-utilization, df, du

The server is running on Sun Sparc T5220 machine with Solaris 10 installed. I've run into the disk space problem recently. Done many research but haven't found any solution so i hope can get some help here.

When i do df command, it shows the disk space of root dir 97%. However, when i do du -akd / | sort -nr | more, the largest file I get is about 5G (just more than half of disk space a bit). I checked and there are no open files that use up the disk. I also did reboot the machine but it doesn't help. And i don't know why 2 following files getting the same big size as shown below. 
/platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1
/platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1

```
bash-3.2# df -h
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/md/dsk/d100       9.9G   9.4G   398M    97%    /
/devices                 0K     0K     0K     0%    /devices
ctfs                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/contract
proc                     0K     0K     0K     0%    /proc
mnttab                   0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                    42G   1.6M    42G     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                    0K     0K     0K     0%    /system/object
sharefs                  0K     0K     0K     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1
                   9.9G   9.4G   398M    97%    /platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr                                               .    so.1
 /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-         T5220/lib/sparcv9/libc_psr/libc_psr_hwcap2.so.1
                   9.9G   9.4G   398M    97%    /platform/sun4v/lib/sparcv9/                                            libc_psr.so.1
fd                       0K     0K     0K     0%    /dev/fd
/dev/md/dsk/d104        20G   3.2G    16G    17%    /var
swap                    42G    40K    42G     1%    /tmp
swap                    42G   144K    42G     1%    /var/run
/dev/md/dsk/d103       7.9G   340M   7.5G     5%    /opt
/dev/md/dsk/d106        81G    83M    80G     1%    /extra
/dev/md/dsk/d466        15G    13G   1.6G    89%    /zones/sss0030d
/dev/md/dsk/d166        15G   9.4G   5.2G    65%    /zones/sss0030a
/dev/md/dsk/d277        20G    13G   6.9G    65%    /zones/sss0030j
/dev/md/dsk/d366        15G    12G   2.2G    85%    /zones/sss0030c
/dev/md/dsk/d766        21G    13G   7.3G    65%    /zones/sss0030g
/dev/md/dsk/d266        15G    11G   3.9G    74%    /zones/sss0030b
/dev/md/dsk/d566        15G    12G   2.3G    85%    /zones/sss0030e
/dev/md/dsk/d666        15G    10G   4.5G    70%    /zones/sss0030f
/dev/md/dsk/d177        20G    12G   7.7G    61%    /zones/sss0030i
/dev/md/dsk/d866        21G    13G   7.2G    65%    /zones/sss0030h
/dev/md/dsk/d105       7.9G   232M   7.6G     3%    /export/home
bash-3.2# du -akd / | sort -nr | more
5172979
4725945 /usr
1231625 /usr/lib
627635  /usr/jdk
566614  /usr/jdk/instances
486350  /usr/openwin
448980  /usr/sfw
....
```

Comment: These ```libc_psr_hwcap2``` objects don't use disk space, see  [Doc ID 1012769.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1012769.1 "Why do libc_psr_hwcap1.so.1 and libc_psr.so.1 show as mount points?") and this [BigAdmin feature](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/library-coolthreads-jsp-140937.html "LOFS Mounted Platform-Specific Routine Libraries With CMT UltraSPARC Processor-Based Systems") for a somewhat technical documentation on these.

Comment: Thank you. So the question about those files is solved. How about df and du show different disk usage and a reboot doesnt fix it. Do you know why?

Comment: Unfortunately not. All I can think of is "open files" (but you rebooted already) and "maybe du(1) missed something". I'd love to take a look myself, but I doubt that this might be possible, hm? :-)